# A problem when creating an instance of JSONObject

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I am new to java, and I have seen a lot of people using JSONObject like this:

```
 String content ="....";
 JSONObject Object1 = new JSONObject(content);
```

But when I do that, there appears that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEx1H.png)

What's wrong, please help me.(I have "import net.sf.json.JSONObject")

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is there any error message you could share?

Answer (score 0):

The `JSONObject` you provided is from the popular [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library which contains a [constructor](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-) like your example.

So simply switch to this lib.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems, is that you are importing the wrong library. 
The library that you are using doesn't have a constructor that receives a string parameter only a boolean:

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(boolean)

The library that you are trying to use when you are initializing a new instance of `JSONObject` is from Google:

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#JSONObject(java.lang.String)